# What is the equation to make a concentric spiral that isn't an Archimedean Spiral?

Tags: geometry

I've googled spirals, and the only ones I get are Archimedean Spirals. I'm looking for an equation that would create the spiral below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$r = k \theta$, where k is a constant.

Edit - As saulspatz pointed out, this describes the Archimedian spiral. But that is what the picture shows.

There are other spirals. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_spirals) lists some.

Comment: Specifically, if you want spacing $d$ between turns, $k = d / (2 \pi) = d / 360^\circ$, i.e. $$r = d \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} = d \frac{\theta}{360^\circ}$$and if you prefer a Cartesian coordinate system,$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned} x & = \frac{\theta d}{2 \pi} \cos \theta \\ y & = \frac{\theta d}{2 \pi} \sin \theta \end{aligned}\right.$$

Comment: I thought $r=k\theta$ *is* an [Archimedean spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral).